# time series forecasting visit dates with customer classes graph not accurate

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, forecasting

I am trying to do time series forecasting on a bunch of classes and date time but my graph looks like this for some reason my full code is below:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount = True)

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['time_date'], index_col='time_date')
class_id = data['class_id']
time_date = data.index.date
data['date'] = data.index.date

class_id = data['class_id']
time_date = data.index.to_series()
m1 = class_id.ne(class_id.shift())
m2 = time_date.dt.date.ne(time_date.dt.date.shift())
data['count'] = data.groupby((m1 | m2).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values

out = data[data.groupby(data.index.date).transform('size').gt(1)]

!pip install pandas-datareader

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

plt.ylabel('Amount of classes')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

out.index = pd.to_datetime(out['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
plt.plot(out.index, out['count'], )
```

[image: results of plt]

while the [blog](https://builtin.com/data-science/time-series-forecasting-python) where I got this time series code from has this kind of result

[image]

So I'm not sure if I should proceed or not XD

my input data is this:
timestamp / class_id
2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C
2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B
2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B
2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C

after processing it and adding count and date columns:
count / timestamp / class_id / date
1 / 2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A / 2021-09-27
2 / 2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A / 2021-09-27
3 / 2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A / 2021-09-27
1 / 2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C / 2021-09-27
1 / 2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B / 2021-05-23
2 / 2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B / 2021-05-23
1 / 2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C / 2021-05-23

I tried a code below but for some reason the first graph is empty

```
plt.ylabel('Amount of classes')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

out.index = pd.to_datetime(out['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
out.groupby('class_id').plot()
plt.plot(out.index, out['count'], )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are plotting all your `class_id`'s at the same time. Try plotting by class using something like `out.groupby('class_id').plot()` to see if the plots per class make sense and look like you expect.

Comment: hi I tried your code and it works some how but for some reason the first graph is empty I've added the screenshot in the question

Comment: The labels on the plot don't match the ones in the code snippet. are you sure it's from the same code? Your snippet also has two plot calls one after the other.